# Free HTML5 slider that can show text, images and videos

Tags: library, javascript, html, css

I am looking for an HTML5 slider (script, CSS bundle) that is responsive, can include both text and rich content like video or images. Here is an example:

[image: slider example]

This is not a question of a program recommendation but a library or at least script and CSS bundle (which is also a software recommendation in my opinion).

The script could be for free or cost something. I want something that is good looking and has a clean markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to embed bootstrap and use it's carousel. Plus it's mobile-friendly!

You can check out this demo : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

And here are the docs : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

I'm not sure but I think you can even take only the `carousel.js` file and it will provide the feature you need. That is if you do not want all the bootstrap's nice features. To get only this file, download the source and take it from the js folder.

Comment: This is a good option since I am using bootstrap anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've always had a lot of joy with jCarousel for this sort of thing: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel

The examples on the jCarousel site are only showing images, but you can include any arbitrary HTML in the `<li>` elements that make up the slides.

Comment: Seems to be responsive too!

Comment: Aye, it's pretty good, but if you're using Bootstrap already then you might as well use its built-in stuff, as you say.